# High-res icon in Windows Vista alt-tab thumbnail preview?

Tags: windows-vista, icons, thumbnails, preview, alt-tab

I have customized my alt-tab screen with the following:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\AltTab]
"OverlayIconPx"=dword:00000040
"MaxThumbSizePx"=dword:00000100
"MinThumbSizePcent"=dword:00000064
```

It works great: the thumbnail becomes 256 pixel wide and the icon at the corner of the thumbnail becomes 64x64 pixels.  However, Windows doesn't load the high-res icons from the programs; instead, it uses the 16x16 pixel icon and scaled it up by nearest-neighbor.  I'm sure the programs has high-res icons because I saw them with in "Extra Large Icon" view in Explorer.

So the question is: How can I force Windows to load the high-res icons for the alt-tab thumbnail preview?  (Perhaps a registry key, or a .dll hack/injection?)

Comment: To clarify: the thumbnail is good; my problem concerns the icon overlaid at the corner of the thumbnail.

Answer (score 1):

I'm adding another answer, since according to what you say, Vista's Alt-Tab isn't smart enough to use the 256x256 icons, even if there's room for them in the display.

You might consider using, as an alternative to Vista's Alt-Tab, the free product [Switcher](http://insentient.net/). With it you can view your actual windows in three ways: dock, grid, and tile.

See a description of it in the following article :
[A Better Alt-Tab Replacement Tool for Windows](http://www.labnol.org/software/alt-tab-replacement-for-windows/9329/)

Below is the grid-mode display:

[image]

Comment: Why so? Software is software.

Comment: And free is free as in beer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, but if you want a better app-switcher on Vista/7, try pressing Win-Tab. It shows the full window.

Answer (score 0):

You might not have changed all the required settings.

From [How to make Vista Taskbar Previews and ALT-TAB Thumbnails Bigger](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CommentView.aspx?guid=755c1465-9a71-4433-9482-ecc0871e5ec7):

> Save this to a .reg file and run as
>   Administrator:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\AltTab]
"OverlayIconPx"=dword:00000023
"OverlayIconDXPx"=dword:00000000
"OverlayIconDYPx"=dword:00000000
"ThumbSpacingXPx"=dword:00000004
"ThumbSpacingYPx"=dword:00000004
"SideMarginPx"=dword:00000004
"BottomMarginPx"=dword:0000000a
"MinThumbSizePcent"=dword:00000064
"MinWidthPx"=dword:0000012c
"TopMarginPx"=dword:00000020
"MaxThumbSizePx"=dword:000000dc
"MaxIconSizePx"=dword:0000015e
"TextBottomPx"=dword:000001f4
```

> I've also tightened up the borders and
>   margins a bit, to make room for larger
>   thumbnails. However, before importing
>   this into your registry you must edit
>   the MaxThumbSizePx to a size that
>   works on your monitor first! The
>   current value, above, is DC hex or 220
>   decimal, which works on my 1600 x 1200
>   primary monitor. The maximum row size
>   is 7, so each row is 7 x 220 = 1540,
>   right under the 1600 width.

Comment: I actually started off with all these keys, but I find most of them unnecessary (e.g. I don't want to tweak the margins), so I removed them.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but the above combination is said to work. You might try it and see. You can export your current values to keep while experimenting.

Comment: They do work, but they don't address my question.

Comment: @netvope: What do you mean?

Comment: My question is "How can I force Windows to load the HIGH-RES icons for the alt-tab thumbnail preview?". I have also clarified that "My problem concerns the ICON overlaid at the CORNER of the thumbnail". I have no problems making the thumbnails and the icons big with the registry entries. But LOW-RES icons look terrible when they are big. I want HIGH-RES icons so that they look good when they are big. Please read the question carefully.

Comment: Has anyone used procmon to detect how to change the rowsize. I want it to be 3/4 with bigger thumbnails. 7 is a bit too much.